# MySQL search by special ID

Tags: mysql

I have item and a category for this item. Category have an ID. I need to put category ID for item in DB, but item can have 2,3 or more categories. And what I need to do?
In items table make a new cell name "category" and put categories id with comma (7,4,8...)? If this way then how to search by category in PHP?

Comment: You must read about `RDBMS` concepts before starting do it.

Comment: Well, depending on the engine you're using, you could create table with categories and use foreign keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem you have an item that can have multiple categories.  If that is the case, you do not store the multiple categories in the same column.

You would want to set up your tables in this manner:

```
create table item
(
  id int,  (PK)
  name varchar(10)
);

create table category
(
  id int,  (PK)
  name varchar(10)
);

create table item_category
(
  item_id int,  (FK)
  category_id int  (FK)
);
```

This would allow you to have your items and categories in separate tables and then use a join table to allow your item to have multiple categories.

If you had the following sample data for the tables above:

```
insert into item values
  (1, 'item 1'), 
  (2, 'item 2');

insert into category values
  (1, 'category 1'), 
  (2, 'category 2');

insert into item_category values
  (1, 1), 
  (2, 1),
  (2, 2);
```

Then your query would be similar to this:

```
select i.id item_id,
  i.name ItemName,
  c.id CategoryId,
  c.name CategoryName
from item i
left join item_category ic
  on i.id = ic.item_id
left join category c
  on ic.category_id = c.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1e0a/3).  Which gives the result:

```
| ITEM_ID | ITEMNAME | CATEGORYID | CATEGORYNAME |
--------------------------------------------------
|       1 |   item 1 |          1 |   category 1 |
|       2 |   item 2 |          1 |   category 1 |
|       2 |   item 2 |          2 |   category 2 |
```

Comment: It's very huge variant, 3 tables isn't good. I like the previous variant with foreign keys. But it is one of varients.

Comment: @user1821941 Why isn't 3 tables good?  Then you have the category and item listed in their respective tables once. You will then have multiple entries in the join table as needed.